# How to set Environmental Variable?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, maven

Please tell me how to set environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME
MAVEN_HOME
TOMCAT_HOME
PATH
```

I installed Java via terminal apt-get command, Tomcat and Eclipse by downloading tar.gz files and extracting them. Maven also by terminal and by getting plugin to eclipse too.

Please tell me a answer step by step. I'm beginner to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a terminal and type :

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`

and consequently for the others

Don't forget these values will be only available in your current terminal session. You'll have to add these to a persistent environnement file like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` to keep them among a terminal session restart

To check for existing variables, type `env`

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear whether you want to set from a program or what, but, in a `bash` shell, the syntax is: `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/JDK`